# Can the polynomial $x_0$ restrict to $0$ on the coordinate chart $U_{x_0}$ or only to $1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can the polynomial $x_0$ restrict to $0$ on the coordinate chart $U_{x_0}$ or only to $1$?

I'm trying to figure out whether $\mathbb{A}^{1} \backslash \{0\} = \mathbb{P}^{1} \backslash \{[1:0],[0:1]\}$ is obtained from the vanishing of the polynomials $x_0$ and $x_1$ in one coordinate chart or a union of two coordinate charts.